# Tcl calling maxima

Tags: tcl, maxima

How to send and receive data from external program in tcl? I'm try this:

```
set d exec maxima --batch-string='5+10;'
puts d;
```

But its didn't work. I need to call Maxima(http://maxima.sourceforge.net/index.html) from tcl and return in tcl maxima results. Official documentation is empty or very old and examples not working.

Comment: You'll need to explain in more detail exactly how it it is not working. Also, take a look at the related projects page (http://maxima.sourceforge.net/relatedprojects.html) -- several projects are user interfaces which use Maxima to compute results. Perhaps you can copy one of them.

Comment: @RobertDodier, i don't need copy a full gui for maxima. I want create interface on Tcl/Tk only for 1 task, that will call maxima with params that user will put in my interface, and output maxima results in my interface

Comment: What I am suggersting is that perhaps you can copy only the part of a GUI project which communicates with Maxima, or at least see how they do it and create your own communication method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've wrote the function `maxima_call` to easily call Maxima. You need to set your own path to Maxima program in `maxima_path` variable. On Linux it could be `set maxima_path maxima`

```
proc maxima_call {expression} {
  set maxima_path "M:\\Programs\\maxima-5.40.0\\bin\\maxima.bat"
  set keys ""
#  set keys "display2d:false\$"

  set result [split [exec ${maxima_path}  --batch-string=${keys}${expression}\;] \n]
  set result [lreplace $result 0 4]
  return [join $result \n]
}

puts [maxima_call "5+10"]
```

But I'm not clearly understand how are you going to parse results of calculation. For example, i've got this output from Maxima.

```
set expression "\[aa : 1, bb : 2, cc : 3\]; (aa + bb + cc)/(dd + ee)"
puts [maxima_call $expression]
```

>

```
(%i1) [aa:1,bb:2,cc:3]
(%o1)                              [1, 2, 3]
(%i2) (aa+bb+cc)/(dd+ee)
                                       6
(%o2)                               -------
                                    ee + dd
```

Comment: Re: "But I'm not clearly understand how are you going to parse results of calculation. For example, i've got this output from Maxima." Maxima honors the global flag `display2d` to determine whether to use the pretty-printer (so-called "2-d" display) or in machine parsable output (so-called "1-d"). `display2d:false;` disables the pretty printer.

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess that you would be best off doing a call something like this:

```
set theBatchString "5+10;"

set d [exec maxima --batch-string=$theBatchString]
puts $d
```

I've split the batch string into its own variable for clarity, and bear in mind that single quotes don't actually mean anything to Tcl; they're a shell-ism. Tcl uses different syntax.